# How will I write text in the center of the square

Tags: html, css

Here is my link http://jsfiddle.net/sanand29/7fh2em4f/

```
<div class="link1">
              <a href="#" class="square1"></a>
    <div>
```

the css part corresponding to it

```
.link1
{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15%;
    width: 78%;
    margin-left: 26%;
}
a.square1
{
    width: 50%;
    height: 50%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 9%;
    margin-top: 0%;
    background-color: #FAFAFA;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

How will I put any text in the center of the square keeping it responsive.

Comment: answer: don't change anything?.. whats wrong with current behavior?

Comment: nothing is wrong. I just can't figure out how will i insert texts in the center of the square

Comment: Just place it in `<a>` tag. `<a href="#" class="square1">some text</a>`. Or you want to do it with CSS?

Comment: I tried using that but texts come with an underline and i want to use css and allign texts to center without any underline. can u show me that

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<div class="link1">
          <div class="square1">Text to be centred</div>
</div>
```

And the css

```
div.link1 {position: relative; width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid red;}
div.square1 {height: 20px; text-align: center; margin: auto; position: absolute; top: 0px; left:0px;      bottom:0px; right:0px;}
```

This will keep the text in the middle of the box. In fact it keeps the div with class square1 centred - the text may overflow this div, depending on the size of font you choose. If you set the height of the div to the height of your font you can't go wrong.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sanand29/rVDvk/3/ this is what i got. The squares are not showing as a link and I don't think its responsive

Comment: Try it again - looks like jsfiddle needs the "px" in the CSS.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sanand29/7fh2em4f/.. This is what I got when I inserted texts inside the square. Problem is before the insertion of text, size of the square is different and after insertion size changes. How can I avoid that?

Comment: I think that's the same as your first fiddle. Couple of things - <a> is an inline element, so margin, width and height won't do anything unless you set display to block. If you just want text in a box, put it in a <div> - no underline.